# Webdriver CSS locators suddenly stopped working on IE11, while xpath locators do work

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, internet-explorer-11

Suddenly webdriver CSS locators stopped working in my code. (they were working a few days ago)

When i open up IE 11's  developer tools (By pressing F12 in Internet Explorer) i see a general error saying "
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified"  but it doesn't show me the locator itself

is there a way to test css locators on developer tools,  or to check what is IE seeing ?

the command i pass is very straightforward :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span:contains('Information')")));
```

Comment: Hi, i think css selectors with contains text will not work in webdriver..correct?

Comment: As mentioned - the selectors worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

`:contains` is not part of CSS3.

Please refer https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

You may try `By.cssSelector("span[innertext='Information']")`

Comment: true it's not part of css3, but it is supported by selenium (Selenium supports also css1 and css2 which do support this search type).
see this link (at the bottom) for example: https://saucelabs.com/selenium/css-selectors

I have been using these for almost a year. suddenly it stopped working

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx as per IE CSS compatibility documentation, it doesnt have `:contains` selector. If IE doesn't support, selenium cannot do anything.

Comment: @Dror `:contains` is not a part of any CSS standard. Full stop. Don't confuse what may have been available in the long-deprecated Selenium RC API with what is available in the Selenium WebDriver API. RC used Sizzle, the jQuery CSS selector engine, while WebDriver defers to the browser's native CSS selector engine. The SauceLabs page you linked to is specific to RC, and you can tell by its reference to `css=` in the locator, which is an RC construct.

Comment: @JimEvans , parishodak :   your comments are appreciated

It's just very strange to me that after working with IE11 for some time now - with the exact syntax used above , with webdriver (though the SauceLabs page link I've referenced was about RC) , suddenly this issue crops up, and not a long while before.